# An isomorphism is a mono and epi

Tags: category-theory

This must be very easy, but how to prove that an isomorphism is an epi and also a mono?

Suppose $f:X\to Y$ is an isomorphism. This means there is an arrow $g:Y\to X$ such that $fg=1_Y,\ gf=1_X$.

To show $f$ is an epi, suppose $h,h':Y\to Z$ are arrows and $hf=h'f$. We must show that $h=h'$. There must be some kind of trick with composing something with identities, but I don't know what the trick is. For example, we can write $hf=h1_Yf=hfgf$ or something like that, but I don't see how this can be helpful.

And similarly, I don't see what to use to prove that $f$ is an mono. To this end we need to show that if $h,h':Z\to X$ are arrows, then $fh=fh'\implies h=h'$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To show that it is epi, simply precompose with $g$. I.e.,
$$hf=h'f \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad hfg=h'fg \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad h=h'$$
since $fg=1$. Similarly, to show that it is mono, postcompose with $g$
$$fh=fh' \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad gfh=gfh' \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad h=h'$$
since $gf=1$.

Comment: Just to add: this shows that just having a right inverse makes an arrow an epimorphism, and just having a left inverse makes it a monomorphism. There are names for these kinds of epis/monos: split epi/mono. So in particular, an isomorphism is split epi and split mono.

Answer (score -1):

We will shot that $f$ is mono.

Lets suppose that there are $a,b\in X$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$. Then, we will apply $g$:

$$g(f(a))=g(f(b))~\Rightarrow~ 1_X(a) = 1_X(b) ~ \Rightarrow~a=b.$$

We will shot now that $f$ is epi:

Let be $c\in Y$, since $c=c$, we may write $1_Y(c)=c$.
but: $$1_Y(c)=f(g(c))~\Rightarrow~ \exists d\in X ~ (d=g(c)),~ \mbox{ s.t } f(d)=c $$

which means that $f$ is also epi.

Comment: Probably I should have stated it explicitly, but $X$ is an arbitrary category. The statement $a\in X$ does not make sense.

Comment: Yea, you should

Comment: I don't agree. The question is tagged only with [tag:category-theory] and makes no mention of sets, functions, or the category of sets. There's no reason to expect it to be about sets and functions, and that should go without saying. If I asked a question about modules, I shouldn't need to specify that I don't mean specifically complex vector spaces.

Comment: yes, there ir one reason: didn't see it